# How many columns are in this data set?

Tags: sas

[image]

Asked how many columns there are on an exam. I hastily put 3, then 2, and both were graded incorrect. What am I missing?

Comment: maybe 12 (as number of variables indicate)?

Comment: Thank you! Looking at Excel data for so long I'm having a hard time discerning columns/variables.  If it's anything other than 12, I'll update.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Datasets don't have "columns", they have VARIABLES.

The output from the PROC CONTENTS is showing that STORM_SUMMARY has 12 variables.

Comment: Thank you! It was a "trick" question given by my professor. I appreciate the feedback and the explanation!